# Find the angle between two given lines 2D

Tags: matlab

I am getting as an input 4 points.

p1=(x1, y1), p2=(x2, y2), p3=(x3, y3), p4=(x4, y4).

Now I have calculated the distances between p1p2, p2p3, p3p4 and p4p1.

How do I calculate the angle between p1p2 and p2p3 ? which is the angle p2. (shown in image link below);

[image]

I tried this

```
 acos((p1p2)^2 + (p2p3)^2 - (p1p3)^2)/(2*p1p2*p2p3))*(180/pi)
```

But this is not accurate, I want to sum 4 angles and check if they sum to 360. And this way I'll never get an irrational number.

Any help please ?

Comment: *And this way I'll never get an irrational number.* What that has to do with anything?

Comment: My problem is a degree might be 45.772341423 while matlab will show it as 45.77 when summing 4 angles I might get 359.xxxxxx instead of 360.

Comment: You are using floating point math, you will never achieve perfect accuracy.

Comment: In MATLAB, do `format long` to output more decimal places. Won't solve the fundamental issue but might help you visualize results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the angle between two vectors, you simply use their inner product:

```
v1 = p1-p2;
v2 = p3-p2;
```

Normalize to unit vectors and take inner product:

```
n1 = v1/norm(v1);
n2 = v2/norm(v2);

cos_p2 = dot(n1,n2);
```

And the resulting angle is

```
acos(cos_p2)
```

Comment: @Tony please don't forget to mark the answer that helped you most as "accepted" by clicking the green checkmark beside it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, the angle is `acos(dot(||p2p1||, ||p2p3||))`. Try

```
u21 = (p1 - p2) / norm(p1 - p2)
u23 = (p3 - p2) / norm(p3 - p2)
angle = acos(sum(u21 .* u23))
```

The prefix `u` indicates unit vectors.