# In MATLAB how to find the angle between multiple points in array?

Tags: matlab

I have ( they are dynamic) points in my array. How can I find the angle between the edge they make a complete graph(i mean each nodes has equal or more than 2 edges)  ?
these are my points for example :

> 177   159
>   217 104
>   154 69
>   178 92
>   178 125
>   161 100
>   72  32
>   117   67

(as mentioned from [link of duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067083/find-the-angle-between-two-given-lines-2d) i used that code to find angle between each edges.this is my code but the result is strange)

```
for i=1:length(array2)
    for j=i+1:length(array2)-1
        %-------------------------------------
        p1=[array2(i,1),array2(i,2)];
        p2=[array2(j,1),array2(j,2)];
        p3=[array2((j+1),1),array2((j+1),2)];
        %-------------------------------------
        v1=p1-p2;
        v2=p3-p2;
        %-------------------------------------
        n1=v1/norm(v1);
        n2=v2/norm(v2);
        %-------------------------------------
        cos_p2=dot(n1,n2);
        acos(cos_p2)
    end;
end;
```

the result are here. but they are not like angle !!

> ans =
>
> ```
> 1.4491
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.5565
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.0149
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 2.5150
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 2.4880
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.2189
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.2570
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 1.2723
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 1.6740
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 2.5605
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.2002
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 2.3349
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.1923
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.6963
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.2372
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.5972
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 2.0493
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.1460
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 2.8204
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.0591
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.0086
> ```

Comment: You mean the angle in consecutive triangles? Can you post an image of what exactly you mean?

Comment: It is very unclear what is asked. Please define what you mean with "points", "array", "angle", "between", and "them".

Comment: See updated post for 'strange' values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This computes angles between the lines connecting the points in your question:
[image]

```
a = [177 159; 217 104; 154 69; 178 92; 178 125; 161 100; 72 32; 117 67];  

for i = 1:max(size(a))-2
   temp1 = [a(i, 1)-a(i+1, 1), a(i, 2) - a(i+1, 2)];
   temp2 = [a(i+2, 1)-a(i+1, 1), a(i+2, 2) - a(i+1, 2)];
   temp1 = temp1 / norm(temp1);
   temp2 = temp2 / norm(temp2);
   theta(i) = acos( dot(temp1, temp2) )/pi*180;
end
plot(a(:,1), a(:, 2));
```

> theta =
>
> ```
> 83.0272   14.7265  133.7811   34.2157  161.5972    0.4935
> ```

There might be a better way of doing this vectorized, for some more background have a look at [MATLAB Central](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/148079) and this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067083/find-the-angle-between-two-given-lines-2d).

**Update:** The reason why your code gives 'strange' results is probably, because you are getting your angle in radians, whereas in my code I explicitly convert to degrees.